# Github Action is not being triggered from any branch but master

Tags: github, github-actions

I wrote a simple Action that should be triggered only after push in a specific branch named "develop".

```
name: Develop

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'develop'
jobs:
  my-job:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
        - name: run curl command
          run: curl -X POST "https://<site>"
```

As I read, the action .yaml file must be only in `master` branch and so it is.

I expect from this action to be only be triggered for any push to a brach named `develop`.

In practice, no action is triggered when I push to `develop`.

If I change `-'develop'` to `-'master'` and push to `master` branch, I see the action is being triggered.

Comment: each branch has its own action .yaml files.

Comment: @pynexj Not sure how should I implement it? I cannot create a new action under develop branch only.

Comment: In that specific case, is the workflow also present on the `develop` branch?

Comment: Make sure your workflows/YAML files are present on all branches. Best put it on `master`, ensure `develop` is based on `master` and all developers branch off from `master` or `develop` going forward.